# Pass information across page

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I have created a custom page with a drop down (using HTML). When user selects a value, based on the value selected the appropriate collection is displayed. Once user has selected the product and clicked "add to cart", the user lands on cart page. However when in Cart page user wants to click "Continue Shopping" , I want to redirect to the collection based on the value selected by user in the custom page that I had created earlier.

Any pointers on how I can do it.

Comment: Use `cookie` or `localStorage`

Comment: Better use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`

Comment: use session or cookies to store those values, when user clicks "Continue Shopping" redirect him to a page and get all those values from earlier stored cookies or sessions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all the above suggested things should work, which one to use would depend on your use case, basically:

`localStorage` store values for your domain per machine, it won't be removed unless user clear browser cache or you remove it programmatically. i.e. If you want to preserve the value when the user use the same machine (& the browser), then this is your choice.

`sessionStorage` pretty much does the same as `localStorage` except the value will be cleared when you finish the browser session. i.e. close the browser or leave your page.

`cookie` store values 'permanently' like `localStorage`, but the value will be included in all requests and it has a more tight size limit than `localStorage`. If your server does not require the value, you may not want to store in `cookie`.